# Webview and iframe fail to show Youtube videos in a sandboxed iframe in Chrome packaged app

Tags: iframe, webview, youtube, sandbox, google-chrome-app

I am developing a Chrome packaged app (not a legacy packaged app); my app needs to contain a sandboxed `iframe` (to run 3rd party HTML/JS code), in which I need to use a `webview` or an `iframe` to show a Youtube video. Neither works; I cannot play any Youtube videos. (The `webview` works, however, when used outside the sandboxed `iframe`.)

Main HTML file looks like this:

```
 <iframe src="sandbox.html"></iframe>
```

The file `sandbox.html` is declared in `manifest.json`. It looks like this (I'm trying two alternative ways of playing a Youtube video):

```
<webview width="420" height="315" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/XGSy3_Czz8k"></webview>
<iframe width="420" height="315" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/XGSy3_Czz8k"></iframe>
```

When I run this app, the `webview` is an empty white rectangle. The `iframe`, on the other hand, contains a cover image and the Youtube player controls for the video.

Firstly, why is the `webview` empty? The `webview` works in this app (plays video) as long as I use the `webview` *outside* the sandboxed `iframe`. When the `webview` is inside a sandbox, it silently refuses to load anything.

Secondly, there are errors in the console when I run this app:

```
 GET chrome-extension://boadgeojelhgndaghljhdicfkmllpafd/cast_sender.js net::ERR_FAILED www-embed-player.js:140
 GET chrome-extension://dliochdbjfkdbacpmhlcpmleaejidimm/cast_sender.js net::ERR_FAILED www-embed-player.js:140
 GET chrome-extension://hfaagokkkhdbgiakmmlclaapfelnkoah/cast_sender.js net::ERR_FAILED www-embed-player.js:140
 GET chrome-extension://fmfcbgogabcbclcofgocippekhfcmgfj/cast_sender.js net::ERR_FAILED www-embed-player.js:140
 GET chrome-extension://enhhojjnijigcajfphajepfemndkmdlo/cast_sender.js net::ERR_FAILED www-embed-player.js:140
```

These errors come when I load the `iframe` shown above, inside the sandboxed page. These errors are strange (why is Chrome trying to load a JS file out of some random Chrome extensions?)

When I try to start playing the video in the `iframe`, I get sometimes the message "An error occurred" from the Youtube player, and sometimes no message but the player goes black. In all cases, I have this error on the console:

```
 XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://www.youtube.com/get_video_info?html5=1&video_id=S2VXOd3uXh8&cpn=Rso…=en_US&sts=16309&lact=11140&width=300&height=300&iframe=1&c=web&cver=html5. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.
```

My `manifest.json` has all necessary permissions:

```
 "permissions": [
 "http://www.youtube.com/*", "https://www.youtube.com/*", "webview" ],
 "sandbox": {
   "pages": [ "sandbox.html" ]
 }, ...
```

I tried `<object data=...>`, `<embed src=...>`, [MediaElement](http://mediaelementjs.com/examples/?name=youtube]) - none of them works at all in a Chrome app.

I am at a loss and can't find any relevant information on the Web either.

- Why is the `webview` blank when it is inside a sandboxed `iframe`?
- Is there something I can do to make `webview` or `iframe` work inside a sandboxed `iframe` in a packaged Chrome app to show Youtube videos?

Comment: Possibly relevant: (webview tags not available in chrome extensions)[https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=250838]

Comment: Seems that this won't work. Some relevant links: [https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!category-topic/youtube/playing-and-watching-videos/chrome/AY5QGdPhXlE]

Comment: Google says "won't fix" [https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=180390]

Answer (score 1):

You should load the URL directly into the `webview`, not through an `iframe`.
Your main HTML should contain:

```
<webview  width="420" height="315" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/XGSy3_Czz8k"></webview>
```

directly.
I tried loading your URL http://www.youtube.... into the browser sample app, which loads the URL inside a  and seems to work fine.
The browser sample app can be found here for reference:
[webview-samples/browser](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/browser-sample/edggnmnajhcbhlnpjnogkjpghaikidaa/)

Comment: Unfortunately, I must use an `iframe`. Yes, without an `iframe` the `webview` works.

Answer (score 1):

A workaround is to use a `webview` in which to play the videos using an `iframe`.

This creates a bunch of other problems, such as the asynchronous nature of `webview`, the fact that a `webview` will silently unload everything if it's made invisible, etc. But at least videos play.

No other combination works: I tried a `webview` inside a `webview`, or an `iframe` inside of an `iframe`, or a `webview` inside an `iframe`.

Main HTML file:

```
 <webview src="sandbox.html" partition="static"></webview>
```

Inside `sandbox.html`:

```
 <iframe width="420" height="315" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/XGSy3_Czz8k"></iframe>
```

In `manifest.json`:

```
   ... 
   "permissions": [ 
      "http://www.youtube.com/*", "https://www.youtube.com/*",
      "webview" ],
    "sandbox": {
      "pages": [ "sandbox.html" ]
    },
    "webview": {
      "partitions": [
        {
          "name": "static",
          "accessible_resources": ["sandbox.html"]
        }
      ]
    }
```